# Read input from audio/text file and set it to v1alpha1 google assistant as ConverseRequest in Android

Tags: java, android, input, google-assistant-sdk, grpc-java

I have integrated **Google Assistant v1 alpha1 SDK** with android and it's responding as expected on giving a live voice input, but I want it to be able to read user input from a `text/audio file` and then respond.

I guess audio file input to `Converserequest` can be given using `android.media.AudioTrack`, but not sure how. Is there any other way to achieve this ? I have seen various examples to do this in **v1alpha1** using python, but found not even a single example for Java. :(

Or is there a way to tap request parameter in between and modify it explicitly?

Basically, It should be able to read separate audio files from an Android device folder as separate inputs and give corresponding spoken responses. Please help!!!

*** Edit ***
I tried to give recorded audio input explicitly in my speech service as shown below but it is throwing following error:

```
 E/SpeechService: converse response error: # com.google.rpc.Status@4e11a0f7
    code: 3
    message: "Invalid \'audio_in\': audio frame length is too long."
E/SpeechService: converse error:
    io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid 'audio_in': audio frame length is too long.
```

My Code:

```
public void recognize(byte[] data, int size) {

//        if (mRequestObserver == null) {
//            return;
//        }

    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sounds/tmpaudio.wav");

    InputStream is;
    DataInputStream         dis = null ;
    BufferedInputStream     bis;

    try
    {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8000);
        dis  = new DataInputStream(bis);      //  Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data from the saved file

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {

    }

int i = 0;                                                          //  Read the file into the "music" array
byte[] music=new byte[(int) file.length()];
try
    {
        while (dis.available() > 0)
        {
            music[i] = dis.readByte();                                      //  This assignment does not reverse the order
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }

    try {dis.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    data = music;

//        String test = "Hello World";
//        data = test.getBytes();
        size = data.length;
    // Call the streaming recognition API
    mRequestObserver.onNext(ConverseRequest.newBuilder()
            .setAudioIn(ByteString.copyFrom(data, 0, size))
            .build());

}
```

Comment: The v1alpha1 API doesn't support text input. For audio input, it should be as easy as reading in audio data just like you're doing now, and setting the input to the raw bytes.

Comment: Hi Nick, I had tried reading the audio data and setting them as input explicitly, but it's throwing "Invalid \'audio_in\': audio frame length is too long." error. How do i know what frame length is required and then how can i divide audio stream in chunks properly?

Comment: From the documentation, the audio is expected to be sent at the same speed as the sample rate (eg. SAMPLE_RATE bytes/second). In some of our samples, we use 1024 as the number of bytes to read per packet.